# What does it mean when you say "you, there" in English?

Tags: meaning

I was watching Titanic the movie today. In the movie, someone came out of a room and saw another person and said with anger : "You there? "

Does it mean "I am happy you are here" or "I am surprised you are here"  ?

Comment: You said they said it with anger. So why would it mean they were happy? Generally it is considered to be an aggressive (or at least not very polite) way to get someone's attention.

Comment: This question seems unanswerable without further context. It makes no sense for someone to ask "You there?" of a person they are looking right at, much less to do so angrily.

Answer (score 2):

It means neither.  It is an exclamation trying to get the attention of the fellow at a distance.  For that reason it is loud, and thus less than polite.  Thus its most common use is by an authority figure to someone at least suspected of trespassing.

Comment: Seems like a sound answer to me. The comma probably shouldn't be in the phrase for that usage, though, as it indicates a pause, which would come out as addressing someone as "you" and then telling them "there". For example, when arraying schoolchildren, you might point at one and say, "You, there."